# Is it asbestos?

Tags: ceiling, asbestos

At my workplace, right above my head, I have noticed a broken hole in the acoustic plaster ceiling (see pic1 below). As can be seen in the attached closeup (see pic 2 below) it has couple of inner layers where in the middle there is a broken edge with a perturbing fibers. Workplace building has been constructed in between 1996-1999 and the ceiling tiles are probably even newer. And yet, could it be Asbestos up there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @isherwood.
My construction related ignorance has aroused my nightmarish imagination

Comment: it wouldn't really matter if it were, mesothelioma virtually exclusively afflicts miners...

Comment: well, there are several known cases of  indirect exposure, where people used to do some regular office-work and happens that it was in an asbestos containing environment. I agree that asbestos related ailments are significantly more common among the miners, factory workers, and construction workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what "acoustic plaster" is, but that looks like run-of-the-mill drywall (gypsum panel) to me--probably 5/8". What you're calling "fibers" is simply the paper facing. It would be truly remarkable to see asbestos in a building constructed in the last 40 years.

Comment: Agreed no asbestos in many years and sheetrock paper +

Comment: Even if there are fibers, they are probably not asbestos - 5/8" type X has reinforcing fibers (in the gypsum matrix), but they are not asbestos. It IS however somewhat odd that this sort of hole is not promptly patched in a workplace, I don't see any "tiles" nor acoustic treatment in the picture, just drywall, a light fixture and a vent.

Comment: Thanks for the information, guess its the standard policy of "no casualties - don't bother fixing it". Anyway I am about to leave there soon, just wanted to know if I was inhaling some worrisome materials during my stay.

Comment: @Ecnerwal given the amount of disruption that the fun of patching drywall involves I'm not the least surprised that it's been deferred.  Even replacing damaged tiles in a drop ceiling or dead florescent tubes (if no one complains) tends to be batched up until the maintenance person can do them by the box of replacements all in one go.